# How to encrypt file with gpg and a passphrase only?

Tags: encryption, gpg

I have a file that is decrypted with a similar command:

```
gpg --batch --yes -q -d --passphrase-fd 0 -o "/var/file.out" "/var/file.gpg" < /var/secret.key
```

I want to change the content of the `/var/file.gpg` but the decryption should continue work as before. Any idea how to encrypt it (I was able to find some examples with pass phrases (which I suppose is what the key file is used for) and sender and receiver (which I suppose I don't need) and it was not working so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've found what I needed:

```
passphrase=$(head -n 1 /var/secret.key)
gpg --symmetric --batch --yes --passphrase $passphrase --output some.gpg  toEncrypt.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an extra variable use the option `--passphrase-file`:

```
$ gpg --batch -c --passphrase-file /var/secret.key -o some.gpg toencrypt.txt
```

Comment: thanks. this is a thing that I'm no loner using ,though gave you upvote.